# How can I import entity_effects and time_effects from PanelOLS?

Tags: python, panel-data, linearmodels

When I run the code:

```
from linearmodels.panel import PanelOLS, PooledOLS
from linearmodels.panel import EntityEffects, TimeEffects
```

I get the error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'EntityEffects' from 'linearmodels.panel' (/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/linearmodels/panel/__init__.py)
```

I'm trying to do PanelOLS controlling entity effects and time effects as below.

```
model_with_entity_and_time_pcse = PanelOLS.from_formula(f'{dependent_variable} ~ {" + ".join(independent_variables)}', data=df_final, entity_effects=True, time_effects=True).fit(cov_type='kernel')
```

Can you help me import the functions?

Answer (score 0):

ImportError: cannot import name 'EntityEffects' from 'linearmodels.panel' (/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/linearmodels/panel/init.py)

This error clearly states that **EntityEffects is not part of linearmodels** package.

from linearmodels.panel import PanelOLS, PooledOLS

**from linearmodels.panel import EntityEffects, TimeEffects // remove this line**

EntityEffects, TimeEffects are not part of linearmodels package. so remove that line to get rid of this error.

Comment: Then how can i use EntityEffects function? Any packages including it?